# Javascript charting library dimple: failed to run its out-of-example

Tags: javascript, charts, dimple.js

I am playing with dimple, a Javascript charting library.

I downloaded this the zip file at http://dimplejs.org/ and set up a website for it.

However, when I run its examples, no chart is drawn. I keep getting this error message in Firefox Firebug.

dimple requires d3 to run.  Are you missing a reference to the d3 library?

Does anyone know what is missing?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: ave you included this in your code: <script src="/lib/d3.v3.4.8.js"></script>

Comment: Yes. It is included. I am running the original example files.  Firefox firebug did not report anything missing files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've deleted my original answer because our conversation took a misleading tangent.  However one of your comments mentioned:

```
SyntaxError: illegal character var Ï€ = Math.PI, Ï„ = 2 * Ï€, halfÏ€ = Ï€ / 2, Îµ = 1e-6, Îµ2
```

I missed it on first read but this is an encoding issue with the JavaScript references.  You just need to include the page tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Or you can add an encoding to the individual script tags:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="/lib/d3.v3.4.8.js"></script> 
<script charset="utf-8" src="/dist/dimple.v2.1.0.js"></script>
```

Here's the explanation in the d3 library issues:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1444

Comment: John, this makes the examples work out of box. I wonder why these out-of-box examples don't have the correct script links there in the first place? Did I do anything wrong on my side to set up the website?

Comment: When I originally created the examples they were only intended for display on the website so I kept the code to a minimum. Once I set them to run independently I didn't notice the problem because I was running in node.  I'll add the tags to them when I get a chance. You didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: John, thanks very much for follow-up with me. This is a nice library, and I am playing the examples. Another quick question: any plan to include map as part of the package? Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice, but I have no immediate plans - it's an enormous area in its own right and a lot of people are already doing a great job.  If you want a great open-source mapping library I recommend Leaflet.